# Celebration of Eid ul Adha for a vegan muslim

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, food, eid-ul-adha

As you already know during the day of Eid ul Adha, muslims sacrifice an animal (sheep,cow ...) as Ibrahim (pbuh) did in name of God. I'm muslim so I absolutely respect my religion but I'm also vegan for health and ethical reasons (I redirect you to this link if you are interested on "Veganism": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=es6U00LMmC4). I'm not able to kill an innocent being and I can't afford the idea of buying an animal knowing that it is going to be slaughtered. I prefer peaceful relationship with animal and nature. **So am I disobeying to Allah (swt) by refusing to sacrifice an animal and refusing to celebrate Eid ul Adha in that manner**? If yes please give me solid arguments in your answer, if no please suggest me any other way of celebration that does not include animal slaughtering (if it is possible). Please answer if you have an **extended knowledge** on the topic and answer with an open mind . Thanks you in advance!!

*I do not think that eating meat is haram I just abstain from it . *It is a choice!*

Comment: quite unclear question. which is impossible/hard for you? Is it buying the to-be-slaughtered animal or slaughter the animal yourself? For the first case, "yes, you are obliged if you can afford it", and for the second one, "No, you don't have to do it(slaughter it) by yourself. someone else can do it on your behalf".

Comment: @kmonsoor I can't afford the idea of buying an animal knowing that it is going to be slaughtered as I said I'm against cruelty also towards animals!

Comment: @Dipok at your convenient time, plz drop the thought that vegetables are lifeless objects ...

Comment: Please watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fv328ceIm44

Comment: @kmonsoor The reason of my veganism is the fact that I believe that human diet should be herbivorous. When we were child we had no carnivourous instincts, our digestive system is made for an herbivorous diet (compare our digestive system to that of the carnivourous animal: totally different but similar to that of the herbivourous). All major diseases (cancer, heart problems, osteoporosis, diabetes etc) come from a diet based on meat. We can live happily without meat. Vegetables should be our meal not animals this is what I think.

Comment: I invite you all to see the link in the text of my question. It is a long video but it explain better why people become vegan!

Comment: @Dipok You can be vegan while being a muslim, however I would imploy you to watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nlMiI7_oEo because it provides you with an understanding, however I do understand this video is addressing hinduism but I think it relative to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my research goes, I've found that the sacrificing animal(s) on Eid (whether you're a pilgrim at Hajj or a Muslim elsewhere in the world) is not compulsory with Imam Abu Hanifa stating that it is compulsory to those that can afford to do it whilst narrations from ahadeeth such as Muslim state that it is a choice as to whether a Muslim should sacrifice a cow or other animal, so there is differing opinions on that subject matter. That being said, it is highly advised that you follow the Prophet's (saw) example and you gain a lot of reward for doing so.

Comment: You are saying its Waajib to sacrifice but are you saying that you can omit Waajid things from your religion or dont do them....

Comment: Also what about slaughter of animals in Hajj...

Comment: Animal sacrifice is ONLY not compulsory if you can not afford it. But if you can and you don't want to (whatever reason there may be) then as per my humble knowledge, I think this is not permitted. You should do animal sacrifice. It is not obligatory for you to eat the animal you sacrifice.

Comment: For non-pilgrims it is only Wajib per the Hanafi madhab, and even in Hanafi madhab Wajib is not the same as Fard (absolute compulsion). Roughly put, a Wajib is something that is allowed not to do, as long as its not habitual.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR answer:**
As, the question is bit unclear.
Which part impossible/hard for you? 
Is it buying the to-be-slaughtered animal, or slaughter the animal yourself?

For the first case, "yes, you are obliged if you can afford it. Still, you can maintain your "vegan" preference by not eating the meat.", 
and for the second one, "No, you don't have to do it(slaughter it) by yourself. someone else can do it on your behalf".

**Long answer:**

For every financially able Muslim man/woman, it is a obligation to sacrifice a right animal in the name of ALLAH.

update: I'd like to elaborate on this.

It is the way guided by Allah(jallashanuhu):

> Therefore turn in prayer to your Lord and sacrifice(وَانْحَرْ) (to Him
>   only)

[al-Qur'an 108:2](https://quran.com/108/2)

It is the way of Muhammad (ﷺ), as he said:

> Whoever offers a sacrifice after the prayer has completed his rituals (of Eid) and has followed the way of the Muslims.

[sahih al-Bukhaari, 5545](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/51990)

So, the ruling is like this :

> Hence the Muslims are unanimously agreed that it is prescribed in
>   Islam, as was narrated by more than one of the scholars.
>
> But they differed as to **whether it is Sunnah mu’akkadah (a confirmed
>   Sunnah) or it is obligatory** and it is not permissible to omit it.
>
> The majority of scholars are of the view that it is **Sunnah mu’akkadah**.
>   This is the view of al-Shaafa’i, Maalik and Ahmad according to his
>   most well-known view.
>
> Others were of the view that **it is obligatory**. This is the view of
>   **Abu Haneefah** and one of the views narrated from Ahmad. This was also
>   the view favoured by Ibn Taymiyah who said: “This is one of the views
>   narrated in the madhhab of Maalik, or it appears to be the view of
>   Maalik.”

more elaboration with sources on: https://islamqa.info/en/36432

You can have your own liking, as a Muslim, as long it is within the halal.

But, avoiding meat, in whole, will not be the best. There's a reason the almighty Creator made human foods so versatile. And, guess who's the role model who has been sent to guide the humanity. 
He enjoyed meat his entire life.

Comment: a good anwer without references! you said to elaborate it but it is not elaborated yet.... You should fulfill your promise.

Comment: Great answer, love to see something in accordance with my answer

Comment: @RehanUllah i guess now it can be considered `fulfilled` ;). a bit late though ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think Muhammad ahsan is a bit exagerating. There is also this hadeeth saying if you eat meat for 40 days continously, you will fall out of Islam and therefore not a muslim anymore. What I think is that we should adhere to the main principles of the sunna ALWAYS. But we can make choices regarding the details in which Allah has made halal. For example you can't say we all HAVE TO ride camels and horses every where for transportation because the prophet (pbuh) did this in his time. Time changes. So do the requirements of differing ages. To me, veganism is helping the planet over the increasing amount of greenhouse gasses (in this case, methane gas) and over the growing climate change. Though since Allah is the creator of animals and he himself allows the issue, of course with the regulations Islam has set for animal slaughtering, which might be the most ethical in its kind (for example it is more Islamic to not slaughter an animal in front of its own kind, which I think this alone can tell us animals have feelings), I think you cannot call this complete animal cruelty for the usual animals people eat. (it might hurt to see your kind killed in front of your eyes but I don't think for example chickens would notice which of those grown chickens were once their chicks, let alone noticing their absence)

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this Hadith or did you lie against the Prophet?

Answer (score -1):

Muslims is who accepts Allah's orders and will and accept it with his heart.

*There was no human more kind than **Prophet Muhammad PBUH** ever born on this planet earth. So if **Prophet PBUH** did it then you should too.*

**Prophet Muhammad PBUH** was the ultimate doctor, ultimate guide for ways of life and ways of livings so we should follow everything he did in his life.

Eid-ul-Azha actually means that sacrificing healthy and best animal for Allah

> Allah says further: (It is not their meat nor their blood, that
>   reaches Allah: it is your piety that reaches Him: He has thus made
>   them subject to you, that ye may glorify Allah for His guidance to
>   you: And proclaim the Good News to all who do right.) (Al-Hajj 22: 37)

If you think that Prophet never insisted to eat meat because there were no campanion of Prophet PBUH who did not follow Prophet's PBUH footsteps in every way of their life

> The Prophet said “the master of all foods is the meat”
>
> "Say to them: If you love God, follow (and love and honor) me, and God
>   will love you" (3:31).
>
> The Prophet said: "Anyone who dislikes my sunna is not of me."
>
> (Bukhari and Muslim)

Comment: So Veganism could not fit with Islam? I've to sacrifice an animal even though I'm not capable to do that? I'm disrespecting my religion by abstaining from causing cruelty to innocent animals?  Sorry for the several questions but your answer is not clear at all :)

Comment: If Veganism was better choice for all humans then Prophet Muhammad PBUH would be a vegan but he was not...So please if you can't do it you should accept error in yourself not in our Religion. Prophet PBUH loved meat and ate it all his life.

Comment: The Prophet did not obliged muslims to eat meat (if He did please reply me) so if a vegan diet makes feel me better I choose a vegan diet. Where is the problem? By doing so I'm not absolutely hating my beloved Prophet!! (I didn't talk about error in Islam...)

Comment: Yes it is the biggest pillar of faith to follow Prophet Muhammad PBUH and his campanions

Comment: If you just want to eat Vegetables, then you are ignoring a lot of Prophet's PBUH Sunnah

Comment: According to Hamza Yousaf there was a vegan companion of the Prophet (puh). His video can be found on youtube though he doesn't provide any references in that. Assuming the likes of him wouldn't lie blatantly, this argument is fundamentally flawed.