# Does having doubts turn a Muslim into a non-Muslim?

Tags: quran, kufr, doubts

"The believers are those who believe in God and His Messenger, then have not doubted, and have struggled with their possessions and their selves in the way of God; those -- they are the truthful ones." [Quran 49:15]

"[ Allah will say], "Throw into Hell every obstinate disbeliever, preventer of good, aggressor, and doubter" [Quran 50:24-25]

These verses seem to indicate that having doubts will take you outside the fold of Islam.

*Question*: Does having doubts turn a Muslim into a non-Muslim?

Allah should know that human beings can have doubts. But Allah made it such that having doubts turn you into a non-Muslim.

Many Muslims use hadith to prove that having doubts is ok as long as you don't speak about them or act on them. But the Quran verses above prove otherwise.

Comment: yes doubts can but waswasay and doubts are two different things - when you have thought which negates Islam's foundations you need to reject the thought right away and recite Taoz

Comment: @Muhammad What does "taoz" mean? I have not seen this before.

Comment: @G. Bach - Ta'awoth is seeking refuge with Allah. The last two surahs of the Qur'an are often called al Ma'uthatain as this is their main topic.

Comment: Doubt is essential to faith. Because Allah is indeed there, your doubt will make your faith stronger.

Comment: see [Can I be thinking about Islam/Quran](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/37308/136370)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience I divide doubts into two types

**First:** You just have a thought that maybe all religion or Islam is just a product of Humans, maybe all prayers seem useless and similar experiences. And you have these thoughts without any particular reason

**Second:** You read a Hadith/Quran or hear about Islam from someone and think this does not seem right

First problem could have two reasons

- Maybe you are getting farther and farther from the study of Islam and don't have someone to talk to you about Islam (A Muslim with some knowledge to share) Maybe you are not reading Quran as much as you should?

As Quran say

> The believers are only those who, when Allah is mentioned, their hearts become fearful, and when His verses are recited to them, it increases them in faith; and upon their Lord they rely
>   [8:2](https://quran.com/8/2)

You are having waswasays (Unintential thoughts which comes to mind without any reason) so what should you do in this case?

Here is hadith

> Narrated Abdullah ibn Abbas:
>
> AbuZumayl said: I asked Ibn Abbas, saying: What is that I find in my
>   breast? He asked: What is it? I replied: I swear by Allah, I cannot
>   speak about it. He asked me: Is it something doubtful? and he laughed.
>   He then said: No one could escape that, until Allah, the exalted,
>   revealed: "If thou went in doubt as to what we have revealed unto
>   thee, and ask those who have been reading the Book from before thee."
>   He said: If you find something in your heart, say: He is the first and
>   the Last, the Evident and the Immanent, and He has full knowledge of
>   all things.

Arabic Dua is highlighted

[image]

And you said that how could ALLAH be so unfair yes ofcourse ALLAH knows how we human are and have the direct answer from Prophet (Peace be upon him)

[image]

You can see that it's part of Imaan to have waswasay it means that Shaytan is attacking you because you have something which is think you shouldn't have

Second problem could be bacause you don't have enough knowledge maybe what you have heard is not what Islam is but you are unable to confirm because of resources or whatever reason you have - You should ask someone when you have this problem and if you read the Quran/Hadith yourself it could also mean that you didn't understand it right so in this case you should do it (Ask those who have knowledge this is what Quran says)

ALLAH knows best

Comment: I have two questions. My first question is, how do you know I have waswas and not doubts? My second question is, if I had doubts instead of waswas, what should I do?