# Why did Allah(SAW) decide to create 3 religions and not only just 1?

Tags: christianity, theology, judaism, religion

First there was Judaism, then Christianity and finally came Islam.

All 3 of these religions are part of Islam, but not completely. Only Islam is the final complete Islam. But before Islam, Christianity was the Islam and before Christianity Judaism was the Islam and today Islam is the only Islam.

Why did Allah (SAW) send the message of Islam in 3 parts? Why not just in 1?

Comment: You seem to be mistaken about the number of religions. Also Judaism did not exist at the time of Prophet Ibrahim (AS) and earlier.

Answer (score 5):

Allah has only created one religion and only one.

*ان الدین عند الله الاسلام*

We have the same **God**, we are the same **humans**, we have the same **wisdom** which tells us love is good, jealousy is bad, arrogance is bad, sacrifice is good.

What you see as changes are only small tiny changes in commandments + deviations of previous religions.

The verses presented in this narration points out that there other **nations** but only one **religion** known as Islam.

See [Pg. 413](http://www.ghbook.ir/index.php?name=%D8%AA%D8%B8%D9%84%D9%85+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A1+%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%82+%D8%AF%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1+%D8%A2%D9%84+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A1&option=com_mtree&task=readonline&link_id=8002&page=413&chkhashk=E466B71F80&Itemid=&lang=en) & [Pg. 414](http://www.ghbook.ir/index.php?name=%D8%AA%D8%B8%D9%84%D9%85+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A1+%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%82+%D8%AF%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1+%D8%A2%D9%84+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A1&option=com_mtree&task=readonline&link_id=8002&page=414&chkhashk=656F55240C&Itemid=&lang=en) & [Pg. 415](http://www.ghbook.ir/index.php?name=%D8%AA%D8%B8%D9%84%D9%85+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A1+%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%82+%D8%AF%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1+%D8%A2%D9%84+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A1&option=com_mtree&task=readonline&link_id=8002&page=415&chkhashk=DC6C24E712&Itemid=&lang=en)

### EDIT:

But why do we need prophets again and again and again?

- To correct the deviations. Prophets have been killed, their sons have been killed, their successors have been killed, their followers have been killed and tyrants ruled again. If you study history every prophet has a nation in which he is *struggling* to guide them, usually those people are misguided by a tyrant king like Nimrod, Pharaoh, etc.
- To constantly admonish humans. See this narration from [Nahj al-Balaqa](https://www.al-islam.org/nahjul-balagha-part-1-sermons/sermon-1-praise-due-allah-whose-worth-cannot-be-described#allah-chooses-his-prophets):

Then Allah sent His Messengers and **series** of His prophets towards them to get them to fulfill the pledges of His creation, to recall to them His bounties, to exhort them by preaching, to unveil before them the hidden virtues of wisdom and show them the signs of His Omnipotence namely the sky which is raised over them, the earth that is placed beneath them, means of living that sustain them, deaths that make them die, ailments that turn them old and incidents that successively betake them.

*بَعَثَ فِيهمْ رُسُلَهُ، وَوَاتَرَ إِلَيْهِمْ أَنْبِياءَهُ، لِيَسْتَأْدُوهُمْ مِيثَاقَ فِطْرَتِهِ، وَيُذَكِّرُوهُمْ مَنْسِيَّ نِعْمَتِهِ، وَيَحْتَجُّوا عَلَيْهِمْ بَالتَّبْلِيغِ، وَيُثِيرُوا لَهُمْ دَفَائِنَ الْعُقُولِ، وَيُرُوهُمْ آيَاتِ الْمَقْدِرَةِ: مِنْ سَقْف فَوْقَهُمْ مَرْفُوع، وَمِهَاد تَحْتَهُمْ مَوْضُوع، وَمَعَايِشَ تُحْيِيهِمْ، وَآجَال تُفْنِيهمْ، وَأَوْصَاب تُهْرِمُهُمْ، وَأَحْدَاث تَتَابَعُ عَلَيْهِمْ*

How many times do we need to be reminded to do good? To remember death? Remember judgement day? For the same reasons we need to admonishers...

Comment: If we follow the same attributes of religion then why was there a need to send out another religion and change some commandments? Thank you for answering.

Comment: @user3254198 another prophet not another religion. Because people killed the a prophet, or his son or successor and deviated from the one true religion.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it now, there has always been only 1 religion not 3. Islam. But 3 prophets have been send to complete the message of this one religion. Why did Allah (SWT) decide to complete the message of this one religion with 3 prophets and not just one? If Allah (SWT) wanted then he could of completed the message with one.

Comment: @user3254198 Cain killed Abel, Noah only had a handful of people for one ship. Prophet Muhammad himself had only 313 people in the battle of Badr. There has always been very few number of good people

Comment: Allah (SWT) foresaw these deaths happening and if he really wanted then he could of avoided these deaths from happening and made sure that Abel spread the complete message of Islam before he died. Yet he decided that Noah and Muhammad needed to come to complete the message of Islam. There must be a reason for this I'm just curious what it is.

Comment: @user3254198 My last 2 comments were suppose to be just one. I think I confused you. I made an edit to my answer. Please see. Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: "To correct the deviations
To constantly admonish humans." This opens up the question of why there are no new messengers; both of these are clearly necessary from the point of view of Islam now.

Comment: @G.Bach that's a different question which should be asked elsewhere, but a short answer is we still need a divine guider Shias believe the current person is in occultation. Sunnis don't believe there is such a need

Comment: @Honey, it is a nice answer, especially as you pointed out: Allah has only created one religion and only one.

ان الدین عند الله الاسلام

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there isn't just 3 religions ( based on God's worship ). There are many others, too. But, the important thing is that the message sent from God was just 1 thing. ( Which is named 'Islam' in the Quran. )

This 'Islam' is not necessarily the religion which we call 'Islam' today.  But we're trying to make it better, to make it closer to the real message. It's true that we may have misunderstandings about God's messages and their meanings. That's why there is not just one religion ( at least in words. )

Also, If you take a deep look at these 3 religions in our world which you named, They are not parts of something bigger. Each of them tries to give a view of that real 'Islam'. Notice that the word 'Islam' means 'To surrender'. Surrender to who ? the God which we all know. Here, 'Islam' is not the name of the religion which Muslims have. It's the concept of 'Surrender to God'.  Each religion tries to give the best views about this concept.   Consider that we are all humans and we may be wrong sometimes.  That's why we are not sure about how much we are close to that meaning of the word 'Islam'. But at least, we try our best.